# Books on waves with Fourier Transforms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform

There are many waves and oscillations books out there that also include Fourier analysis but very few give the subject a thorough treatment, they just pass it in a few pages. If anybody has any sources(particularly books) that have Fourier analysis and particularly Fourier Transforms, I would appreciate if he could share his information with me.

Waves, Oscillations, Quantum Mechanics or Mathematics books are all ok if they have an intuitive Fourier analysis in them.

Comment: Paul Nahin   http://www.amazon.com/Dr-Eulers-Fabulous-Formula-Mathematical/dp/0691150370/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8         Mostly FT based, not so much on waves, sorry,  skim through the TOC  Its electronics and the math behind it.

Comment: I will check it out.His books seem to be very interesting.Thanks for the recommendetion

Answer (score 2):

[The FourierTransform.com](https://www.thefouriertransform.com) is a website maintained by an enthusiast.  The site is not peer-reviewed, but it looks as though it might provide helpful explanations.

Here's [a link](https://www.askamathematician.com/2012/09/q-what-is-a-fourier-transform-what-is-it-used-for/) which provides some basic introduction to the Fourier transform. And here is another link to [class notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20180417090134/http://info.phys.unm.edu/%7Eideutsch/Classes/Phys491F03/Supplements/Fourier_Transform.pdf) provided by Prof. Carlton M. Caves for an introduction to the Fourier transform.

[Robert N. Bracewell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_N._Bracewell), did some work on Fourier analysis regarding images.  He authored two works on the subject:

Bracewell, R.N., [The Fourier Transform and Its Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073039381) (McGraw-Hill, 1965, 2nd ed. 1978, revised 1986)

Bracewell, R.N., [Fourier Analysis and Imaging](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-8963-5)  (Plenum, 2004)

[Fredric J. Harris](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=6A5XoroAAAAJ&hl=en), Professor of  Electrical Engineering at U.C. San Diego, wrote [a paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20190927122644/https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Ecpb021000/EE%204361/Great%20DSP%20Papers/Harris%20on%20Windows.pdf) on the use of windows with the discrete Fourier transform for harmonic analysis.

Professor [Tom Körner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_William_K%C3%B6rner) is a mathematician and the titular Professor of Fourier Analysis at Cambridge University. He wrote an incredibly complete "introduction" to the subject - simply entitled "Fourier Analysis". The introduction of [a review of the book](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1989-15838-2) states:

[image]
It is not an easy read - but it is really very good, and considered a classic.

These references range from the introductory to the specialized, but I hope you find something helpful in them.

Comment: The link to the "Class notes" does not work anymore.

Comment: @tatan  I eliminated the inoperative link.

Comment: @tatan The notes can be found archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180417090134/http://info.phys.unm.edu/~ideutsch/Classes/Phys491F03/Supplements/Fourier_Transform.pdf).

Comment: @Urb Thanks! Can you please update the answer with the proper link? It would definitely help future readers.

Comment: @tatan Sure, done. Perhaps you don't know, but since you have over 100 reputation, you can [edit community wiki posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) like this one yourself and your edit is applied immediately.