# Fourier Analysis for Physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, fourier-transform

My professor wanted me to master these topics from Fourier Analysis. I need a resource where these topics are discussed in brief. Although i know many of the topics in the list, i prefer a good resource to brush up my rusty knowledge and learn what i don't know. The topics are:

- Fourier series: sin and cos as a basis set; calculating coefficients; complex basis; convergence, Gibbs phenomenon
- Fourier transform: limiting process; uncertainty principle; application to Fraunhofer diffraction
- Dirac delta function: Sifting property; Fourier representation
- Convolution; Correlations; Parseval's theorem; power spectrum
- Sampling; Nyquist theorem; data compression
- Solving Ordinary Differential Equations with Fourier methods; driven damped oscillators
- Green's functions for 2nd order ODEs; comparison with Fourier methods
- Partial Differential Equations: wave equation; diffusion equation; Fourier solution
- Partial Differential Equations: solution by separation of variables
- PDEs and curvilinear coordinates; Bessel functions; Sturm-Liouville theory: complete basis set of functions

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203382/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518442/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15970/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your into solving a lot of examples and gathering some intuition i recommend Schaum's outline series. They have nice solved examples. ([https://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Analysis-Applications-Boundary-Problems/dp/0070602190](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070602190))
2. If you are into more technical mathematical stuff, here is a textbook I used. ([https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Fourier-Analysis-Russell-Herman/dp/1498773702](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498773702))
3. A great way to learn about DFTs and Signal Processing in general, I recommend going through some coding problems and in such case, technical notes from NI and some coding textbooks helped a lot. (https://www.ni.com/ko-kr/innovations/white-papers/06/using-fast-fourier-transforms-and-power-spectra-in-labview.html)

Comment: Hey, I know this is late, but could you please reccomend resources to learn multi-dimensional fourier transforms? Its for a Math Methods in Physics class I am taking now, we need to evaluate 2D/3D fourier transforms as well.... I need something that has a lot of worked examples and follows naturally from where the 1D version leaves off. Couldn't find a single book on this.

Comment: Hey, did you try looking into Mathematical Methods for Physicists by Arfken, Hans J. Weber and Frank E. Harris?

Comment: I did, but i needed something with more worked exaples and clearer explanations. Something with more exercises would be idea. Could you reccomend any? even if its a book for Math Majors I can manage.